# AWS Workmail: Cannot receive email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-workmail

I created a AWS Workmail account and successfully verified my custom domain, which is hosted at Route 53. Then I added the MX entry followed by the four CNAME entries. Now I can send emails from the Workmail account but cannot receive any emails. When I send an email from my Gmail account to the workmail address I get an MAILER-DAEMON "error", that the email cannot be delivered.

I waited now for more than two days to let the DNS spread around the world, so I think I am doing something wrong.

Down below you will find my Route 53 setup for the MX and one CNAME record set.

[image]
[image]

P.S. The problem might be connected to the dot at the end of the CNAME values? Like `---.dkim.amazonses.com.`? I tried both versions.

**Bounce message:**
This message could not be delivered due to a recipient error. Please try again later.

```
Received: by mail-wr0-f179.google.com with SMTP id r74so2588456wrb.13
 for <julian@wegoloco.es>; Sat, 23 Sep 2017 07:13:34 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
 h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
 bh=xcvl1pwCa8tv81pHwT3QQ6JAGR5rw5g4TkDQkVj8Irg=;
 b=CxIJRLPTX+TeSq0iAdOEc980/l3Nk7qHBIa+uNc7crx5Imv4bemQQIqv3UhmyhlwDE
 uZwcQ2ci1qghvlMTJjYrU7e/7GT2QR4wKR4r9fTIUXUBenFmHD5TfFTlTOq0ayMW3fOt
 J3/0QxZw3J6uOec2ufkC/e4TUMHC3z0Gii+wxQsThNo+99MLsA7Bezi3ptfogkQJ9u14
 h3IGcS/an+FUnKKELb/fh+pQMHc6vG129D9wohAb8CAxZgZf3o8WTiaqscWnbfScT2Zd
 qXWEPJWI+vcOL6X8Jj7Uc7kB7Qg4yq1GEbDQUg2IM4cfZvtj2q7wEJCIqOvqU5CC7TtZ
 8ZWQ==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
 h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
 bh=xcvl1pwCa8tv81pHwT3QQ6JAGR5rw5g4TkDQkVj8Irg=;
 b=TaIcqkzM3mEOUyFDSrwPAsn1/shmC03Di9mc0/BnFwbi3oGNaa9UjDxy8WbSYKCESd
 3oNFJoUIusG3syqfdD/wj9F176TlcURKaZZGVQ51JXfLPQP72uaoeONJ1qGT+TTorCvs
 RqVoWlMB2JnQ07D3fkuWC7Nc+hkjAAndHV9aY02YBbDu+FB/W4h7A6Bma/pKpUzHSmyA
 /M6sZTiBcI9ykYgPqnYm2iGuIKsQxAALFNcEQSlgaDgHJwjwx19rK4tt1jdR8L6DNg1o
 xy/v0N4VQKtvD44kgIfBz95poKL2QwUrJ064BeGRgXVXWie6VDgr82ga3tGlm+fgfd4s
 LInQ==
X-Gm-Message-State: AHPjjUgJ0OPwauahFKP9+Ip54qnVxwcYINxqYMWQfArQxFVHF3DrITzK
 2KLn8LXcnPl5ZT5f8OiLGvUUjnYrH8tSDnU6wJnk7w==
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AOwi7QB3wSLzCwwBbkf8Wngc+0FNx1nQ0Tod/4RU8ixbxu7NTFEGL9lsg8uCM3Nihc/mmfQ7wpUgy7BrUuaBFmyrgL4=
X-Received: by 10.223.139.200 with SMTP id w8mr2080407wra.172.1506176013900;
 Sat, 23 Sep 2017 07:13:33 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Dirk Hornung <dirkhornung91@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 14:13:22 +0000
Message-ID: <CAMMk0vh6Aq+mqsptCrXk0wf-KuMrfatgZV9PuSOWYFRgB=Jczw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
To: Julian May <julian@wegoloco.es>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="f403045e9ebc4722250559dbee79"
```

Comment: The trailing dot isn't the issue -- the Route 53 console corrects ambiguities.  Show the bounce message, please.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I hope this is the info you asked for?

Comment: Yes.  I also sent a test email and got a similar response.  My initial conclusion is that it isn't your DNS, but rather something is not right about your Workmail setup, or the Workmail/SES integration... but I will try another test to see if I can confirm anything further.

Comment: Ok. I solved it. I disabled and later enabled the User. Now its working. So I guess AWS messed something up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick to solve the issue was to:

- disable the User
- then enable the User again

Now everything seems to work fine. So I guess there was an error on the AWS side while initializing the WorkMail-User-Account.

Comment: I have been facing the same issue... :( But it didnt solve disabling/enabling

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @p.magalhaes were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Christ - the hours people must have lost to this.

Comment: Amazing! Good find here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Its Working For Me..!!

Same Problem we are facing that mean we couldnt any mail notification in my workmail.

After that we are doing that just goto workmail -> Users -> Click current users just disable and enable the user.

Its surely working in workmail notification mail sending / receiving.